# ksoftirq is NOT using CPU and should be, why?

Tags: cpu-usage, interrupt-handling, softirq

Both Linux 2.6 and 3.8.
Linux setup as a router passing a 3 gig file

Doing a top, %SI is high at 30%, but ksoftirqd is doing 0% CPU. So the question is "What thread is handling the softirq???" I've read the code and it is suppose to be ksoftirqd, but it is idle.

[can't post image, not enough points]

Is this an accounting issue?

dreez

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

When the load can not be handled with %SI, it will be offloaded to softirqd. So you see %SI 30 and %softirqd 0.

From the man page. 
ksoftirqd is a per-cpu kernel thread that runs when the machine is under heavy soft-interrupt load. Soft interrupts are normally serviced on return from a hard interrupt, but it's possible for soft interrupts to be triggered more quickly than they can be serviced. If a soft interrupt is triggered for a second time while soft interrupts are being handled, the ksoftirq daemon is triggered to handle the soft interrupts in process context. If ksoftirqd is taking more than a tiny percentage of CPU time, this indicates the machine is under heavy soft interrupt load.

Comment: i have seen ksoftirq is 100% so how to fix this issue?